# How do Template Refs work inside a constant?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Question about Template Refs in vue

I'm taking a look at the vue documentation about "refs" and in the part where it explains about ref inside a v-for it gives the following example:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([
  /* ... */
])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => console.log(itemRefs.value))
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

I can understand its use in

```
 const itemRefs = ref([])
```

but I couldn't understand why the ref is also applied in

```
const list = ref([
   /* ... */
])
```

In a sandbox it is possible to remove the ref from the "list constant" without harming the function, so what would be the real application inside this constant?

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

// const with ref
const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
  alert(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

// const without ref
const list = ([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
  alert(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ref turns `list` into reactive variable. Whenever new item is appended or it is otherwise mutated, the other functions or template parts watching it get updated. In your example without ref, when you append a new item to the list, it won't be automatically rendered in the template.

I can understand your confusion and I assume you probably come from vue2 world. I can't recommend enough reading vue3 docs about reactivity.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different types of refs:

- `itemRefs` is an array of **template ref**. It's a reference to an html element / vue component from your component template. It's associated to the `ref` attribute on the element.
- `list` is a "regular" ref. It adds reactivity over the array of values. Without it, Vue won't react to the value changes and won't update the rendered component.